# Error al llamar una Activity desde un archivo AAR Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buenas las tengan comunidad de StackOverflow, hoy tengo el sig. problema, intento llamar una Activity que esta dentro un archivo AAR, pero cuando la llama, esta aparece a la mitad de pantalla y la otra mitad es la Activity del proyecto donde la llamer, ademas que botones y algunas imagenes no se muestran.

Se muestra asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando tendria que ser asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/perdongato"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/perdongato"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:testOnly="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
    <activity android:name="com.arturo.linearyscrollbar.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.arturo.linearyscrollbar.Buscar" />
    <activity android:name="com.arturo.linearyscrollbar.Smiteguru" />
    <activity android:name="com.arturo.linearyscrollbar.PaginaWeb" />
    <activity android:name="com.arturo.linearyscrollbar.itemRandom" />
    <activity android:name="com.arturo.linearyscrollbar.BuildMaker" />
    <activity android:name="com.arturo.linearyscrollbar.TodosLosItems" />
    <activity android:name="com.arturo.linearyscrollbar.DatosDeLosItems" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.1.0" /> <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name="com.arturo.almaitu.inicio" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.arturo.almaitu.VisorDeComics" />
    <activity android:name="com.arturo.almaitu.links" />
    <activity android:name="com.arturo.almaitu.paginaweb" />
    <activity android:name="com.arturo.almaitu.MainActivity1" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
        android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.arturo.linearyscrollbar.com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
        android:multiprocess="true" />
</application>
```

Con este codigo llamo la Activity

```
moreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intento  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.arturo.almaitu.MainActivity1.class);
            startActivity(intento);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Aparte de que no me queda muy claro por las imágenes qué te ocurre al ser contenidos distintos, pon el layout de la actividad que intentas abrir, la del aar

Comment: como dice @JaviMollá deberias poner el xml de tu activity para poder ayudarte, ya que ese es el problema :D